# jQuery hide and show multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs that include a photo and text. When a user clicks on the "bio" button the biography text appears.

What would I do to get the bio text to appear if the image is clicked?

And if the biography text is shown and a user clicks a different image how can I make the previous bio text disappear? I don't want it to slide in and out rather just fade in and out.

And this is my jquery:

```
$('.bio-button').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings('.team-text').toggle();
});

$('.team-text .close').click(function () {
   $(this).parent('.team-text').hide();
});


$('.team-member img, .team-member-minor img').click(function() {
if ( !$(this).next('div').is(':visible') ) {
    $(".team-text").slideUp();
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
}
});

$('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

And this is my html

```
    <div id="" class="team-member">
    <div class="team-text">
        <p>hello this is Billy's text</p>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div><!-- .team-text -->
    <div class="team-photo">
        <img width="437" height="293" src="http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/billy.jpg" class="" alt="billy" />                          
        <h2>Billy Senecal</h2>
        <p>Producer / Director</p>
    </div><!-- .team-photo -->
    <div class="bio-button">BIO</div>   
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #team-member -->
<div id="" class="team-member">
    <div class="team-text">
        <p>THis is Mark's text</p>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div><!-- .team-text -->
    <div class="team-photo">
        <img width="439" height="293" src="http://www.mgrear.com/clients/gls/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/mark.jpg" class="" alt="mark" />                            
        <h2>Mark Montalto</h2>
        <p>Editor / Producer</p>
    </div><!-- .team-photo -->
    <div class="bio-button">BIO</div>   
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- #team-member -->
```

Here is a link to a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MGDTech/GT36x/18/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fully certain what you are trying to accomplish with the layout but I think this might accomplish be what you were looking for as far as the jQuery is concerned.

```
$('.team-photo, .bio-button').on('click', function(){
    $('.team-text').fadeOut();
    $(this).prevAll('.team-text:hidden').fadeIn();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kYJBM/

Because the default state of the '.team-text' elements is hidden we just hide them with every click and then use the ':hidden' filter on the fadeIn() to keep it from fading in an already visible element (this is so we can hide a tile if a user clicks on it twice). I think what's confusing is that there are two functions and the second one runs conditionally. It's a shorter way of expressing this:

```
if ($(this).prevAll('.team-text').css('display') === 'none') {
    $(this).prevAll('.team-text').fadeIn();
}
```

(edited for readability)

Comment: Malcolm, yes that is what I am looking for! If you have the time, do you mind explaining this bit of code to me? Particularly the last function? The logic seems to be reversed to my feeble mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want anywhere on the tile to work:

```
$('div.team-photo').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.team-text').is(':visible').hide();
  $(this).siblings('.team-text').toggle();
});
```

If you just want the picture in addition:

```
$('div.team-photo > img').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.team-text').is(':visible').hide();
  $(this).parent().siblings('.team-text').toggle();
});
```

Both of these will hide all other visible `.team-text` elements before displaying their own, as well as hide the associated `.team-text` element should the user click the event again.